# Why it is giving me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

Swapping last two numbers giving ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException...
Please correct me where I am doing wrong as I am new to programming and not able to find the problem...
Thank you in advance...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the Number : ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int m = n;
    int size = String.valueOf(n).length();

    int arr[] = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    System.out.println("The next permuatation will be : ");

    int temp = arr[m - 2];
    arr[m - 2] = arr[m - 1];
    arr[m - 1] = temp;

    System.out.print(arr);
}
```

Comment: This problem presents you with a great opportunity to experiment with and learn to use a debugger. If you're coding with any modern IDE, such as Eclipse or NetBeans, then you've got the tool already on your computer. Please consider running your code through this, set break points and then check the state of your variables as the code runs.

Comment: Or you could use a "poor-man's-debugger" -- sprinkle your program with a bunch of `System.out.println(...)` statements to see what's going on. For example, right under your `int size = ...` statement, have `System.out.println("Debug: size is: " + size);`, and do the same for other variables, especially leading up to the site of the error.

Comment: Of course, you would remove the println statements after you've fixed your bug.

Comment: Next you'll want to read [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array) so that when you do get to the line that prints the array, it won't print nonsense.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HovercraftFullOfEels for the suggestion... This helped me lot and solved my problem...